# eclipse smart auto complete

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am in many of this situations before

```
public Class A {
    public A (C c, D d){
        .........
    }

    method F (G g, H h, I i){ 
        .........
    }
}
```

Then I want to reference Object A and its method in other places

```
Class W{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //A a  = new A();   //line 1

        A a = new A(c, d);  // line 2

        C c = new C();      //line 3
        D d = new D();      //line 4       

    }
}
```

My question is:

- When I do `ctrl+space` on the second opening bracket in line1, and choose the right method signature from the drop down list, it does auto complete by fill in a variable which makes it look like line 2.
- In a normal scenario I have to hand type line 3 and 4, which indeed eclipse should create it for me automatically, because **the choice is obvious**(without new C and D, the auto completed code in line 2, would not work).
- Is there any plug-in in eclipse I can use, which NOT JUST fill in those variables in line 2 but Also creating the line 3 and 4 automatically?

Comment: I'm confused... Please clarify

Comment: CTRL SPACE will suggest many options if there are many available. Use the arrow keys to select the one you want.

Comment: @ZoveGames I think OP wants the IDE to detect that there are no suitable objects existing to pass over, create these objects (`C c new new C();` and `D d = new D();` in this case) and then auto complete the call with this two, automatically created objects.